# Swiper-карусель

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper

Как настроить Swiper чтоб центральная картинка была размером побольше, а боковые чуть поменьше. И есть ли возможность управлять размерами активной и неактивных картинок. Может это возможно как-то в сss? Что б как на фото сделать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Такая карусель делается с помощью добавления еффекта effect: 'coverflow', в js-файле, в настройках Swiper, и уже дальше настраивать этот эффект. Может комуто пригодится.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]